# Add a series of tags at once

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Is it possible to add a series of tags to the interesting or ignored tags?

For example adding `*boring*` to ignored tags, would be the same as adding `boring-questions`, `boring-answers` and `also-boring` separately.

And if not, would it be possible to add it as a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really add a series of tags at once, but what you suggested is basically what exists. [Wildcards.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/).

When you add `*boring*`, it won't break it down to individual tags, but will act like a wildcard filter.

Comment: If I add `*boring*` to my ignored tags, it becomes just `boring` after a page refresh...

Comment: @Veger - it shouldn't do. What happens if you refresh again?

Comment: Oops it did not, only the selected tags shows without the * when lcicking on `*boring*`

Comment: Only thing when I click `*boring*` and questions tagged with `boring-question` and `boring`. The 'questions tagged' list only shows `boring`? (Which was the reason it thought using `*boring*` did not work)